# Read from file on JButton click

Tags: java, swing, file, readline

I'm having an issue with my java project.  I've done my homework through searches and reading and I can't seem to find what I need.  What I need to be able to do is each time I click a button, read a line from a text file and input it to text fields.  I think the latter part won't be difficult as soon as I have an idea on the first.  I have an idea on how to read from the whole file on click but line by line each time is what's getting me stuck.

I'm using this bit to see if the data on each line is what I'm looking for:

```
 private boolean validRecord( String line )
 {
    /** Local Variables **/

    boolean validRecord = true; // Assumes Good Data
    int     counter     = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < line; i++ )
    {
        if ( line.charAt( i ).isDigit )
           counter++;

        if ( !line.charAt( i ).isDigit )
           validRecord = false;
    }

    if ( counter != fieldArray.length )
       validRecord = false;

    return validRecord;
 }
```

If anyone can help I'd appreciate it I'm sure I'm missing something obvious since this is the first time I've dealt with reading from files at all.  Thanks. To clarify further, I want to read the first line the first click and the next line each time it's clicked until the file has been searched all the way through.

```
public void fileReader( String inputFile )
{
    /** Local Constants **/

    final String ERROR = "File Error!";

    /** Local Variables **/

    BufferedReader inStream = null;
    Scanner        in;
    String         line;

    if ( isReadableFile( inputFile ) )
    {
       try
       {
         in = new Scanner( new File( inputFile ) );

         line = in.next();

         while ( in.hasNextLine() )
         {
            line  = in.nextLine();
            int j = 0;

            if ( validRecord( line ) )
            {
                for ( int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ )
                {
                    if ( Character.isDigit( line.charAt( i ) ) )
                    {
                        fieldArray[ j ].setText( line.charAt( i ) +
                                                 BLANK );
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }

            else
               System.out.println( "Invalid Record" );
          }

          in.close();
        }

        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println( ERROR );
        }
    }

    else
       System.out.println( "File not readable" );
}


public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{
    if ( e.getSource()      == btnClear )
       clearTextFields();

    else if ( e.getSource() == btnExit )
       System.exit( 0 );

   else if ( e.getSource() == btnCheck )
   {
        testMagicSquare();
        jtaOutput.setLineWrap ( true );
    }

   else if ( e.getSource() == btnFileInput )
      fileReader( jtfFileInput.getText() );
```

Comment: Why read one line at a time on button click? Why not simply read the whole file into an `ArrayList<String>` at the beginning of the program, and then get the next String in the list on button press?

Comment: That's how my professor wants it done.

Comment: To further clarify as well since I'm new to this particular thing ( file reads ), I just want to be pointed in the right direction so I can still figure it out a bit that's why I didn't leave more code in the original post.

Comment: I switched to BufferedReader instead and am slightly closer.  I know get the first line but never advance past it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a total switch and tried something else.  With scanner I wasn't reading things into the textfields with any success. I decided just for the heck of it to switch to BufferedReader and that worked on the first try.  As for dealing with getting line to line, I made bufferedreader a class variable and made another button to open the file, and the original to check each line on click.

That solved the problem of instantiating/opening the file on each click.

Answer (score 5):

> That's how my professor wants it done.

Fair enough.

- Use a Scanner object,
- Call `if (myScanner.hasNextLine())`
- And if true, get the line via `line = myScanner.nextLine()`.
- Be sure to close that Scanner object when you're done with it by calling `close()` on it *after* checking to make sure that it isn't null.

---

**Edit**
I can't say that I yet understand your code, but I fear that you have all of your file reading code in one spot all in a `while (scanner.hasNextLine())`, and I don't think that this will work. I think that you are going to have to,...

- Create a Scanner object for reading the File and make sure that it has been declared on the class level. That is create a private class Scanner field.
- Open the File with your Scanner when you begin your program, perhaps in the class's constructor.
- Then don't read from it. Not until the button is pressed.
- In your read button's actionPerformed method, check the Scanner *once* to see if it `hasnextLine()`, and if so, call `nextLine()` only *once* on it. No while loop involved here.
- Close the Scanner only when `hasNextLine()` returns false.

Comment: @ScottKocos: try it and see. ;-)

Comment: Thanks we'll give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: I gave it a shot.  It seems I'm getting held up on the part I thought would be simple.  If it passes my validation, which at this point it does, it should fill the jtextfields in my gui with the values in the line.  It however is not doing that.  I'm stumped again.

Comment: I put the method above.  It seems as though either it's not reading properly, or it's somehow failing the last if statement which I highly doubt.

Comment: @ScottKocos: I see no ActionListener, no actionPerformed method posted. I just see you seeming to read through the entire file at one go. You also appear to possibly be closing a Scanner inside the loop that does the reading which would mess things up royal.

Comment: @ScottKocos: I may be wrong about your closing the Scanner. Your code formatting is off as your opening braces don't line up with their paired closing braces making it very difficult to read and understand your code and know which line of code is in which block. You will need to clean your code in your post soon if you want others to be able to understand it and be able to help you.

Comment: I have it outside the while loop?  I added the actionPerformed as it is now.  Yeah I see now things are off.  Things paste sucky in here sometimes.

Comment: @ScottKocos: please read my comment about your code formatting. I/we would appreciate it greatly if you would fix this asap. Also, I don't see in your actionPerformed where you read a line of code. Please clarify.

Comment: instead of if, use while() for while(myScanner.hasNext()) so that it continuously reads until the end of the file

Comment: In that case I guess It's in the wrong spot and that's something I'm confused on.  user, if you read my first post I don't want to read through the whole file at one time.

Comment: Each click, I want to read (if valid) a line of digits into my array of jtextfields.  I think I fixed the alignment.

Comment: @ScottKocos: I know what your goal is. I need to know what your lines of code individually are trying to do since they just don't make sense. Please read the edit to my answer.

Comment: Which part specifically?  I changed it to make Scanner sc a class variable and created it in the try block of the method.  I changed line = in.next() to line = sc.nextLine().

Comment: @ScottKocos: I think I've told you enough so that you can experiment with your code, and I suggest that you do this. The more you experiment the more you'll learn, and it's time for me to go to bed regardless. I'm betting you'll solve this within 15-20 min. Best of luck!

Comment: I also forgot to mention before that there is a jtextfield where the file name is input so I wouldn't really be able to open it on launch.